# Commands not working in ScrapyProject

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I create a virtualenv name as ScrapyProject. when I use scrapy command or pip command it does not work but when I enter the python command it works. Here is how he shows me.

> (ScrapyProject) C:\Users\Jake\ScrapyProject>scrapy
>
> (ScrapyProject) C:\Users\Jake\ScrapyProject>pip
>
> (ScrapyProject) C:\Users\Jake\ScrapyProject>python
>
> python2.7.6 etc.

Here is how my paths are in virtualenv.
C:\Users\Jake\ScrapyProject\Scripts;Then some windows paths then some python paths There is not extra spaces between them I am sure! and here is how my python paths look;C:\python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Can anybody help me If he needs some extra information, I will give you? I totally didnot understand it!

Comment: Remove the `ScrapyProject` env and re-add it again and post the complete output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pip install all the set-up within the virtualenv.

Comment: You need to install pip first. Use this link, https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html